# Azure PAAS write replica

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Situation : I require a copy of a 2Tb database. Currently on azure IAAS we snapshot disk mount new disk and unmount old disk time around 7 minutes. The copy of orginal data is offline for only a few mins whilst data disks are switched. This happens 4 times a day.

I am considering moving to PAAS but need to find a speedy solution to either sync and rename or replica same 2tb database. Export takes to long. Then make the copy database available for readwrite access. The database names and connections must remain the same. 4 times a day.

If anyone knows how or is doing this on azure sql database please share solution.

Comment: You need to create a replica database from the Azure SQL managed instance to Azure SQL database, then sync the data between the two database,  am i right?

Comment: From azure SQL db to another version of db in azure sql db.  copy and export take too long as the copy db needs to be on line for as much of the day as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure I understand what you need to do, but it looks like DBCopy is what you are looking for:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy#copy-a-database-by-using-transact-sql

It will create a copy of your database and the copy will be read/write. Do you need the second copy for QA/TEST?

Comment: As I mentioned db copy is too slow after 6 hours db is stale. I need the db new copy to be available upto 15 mins after. The db copy will take its time copying . What I am after is a method to sync and break. So data has it 6 hours lifespan not use several hours of that 6 hours copying or exporting.  Not as qa/test a live full accesed db but replicated from prod.

Comment: You have two options then: 1) The only way to have a database copy available almost immediately is using a secondary replica (via Business Critical or Hyperscale tiers). The secondary replica will no be writable though. 2) The other option could be to use GeoDR to keep a secondary copy synced in near-real time. When you need to create a writeable copy, you simply break the GeoDR process. Since restarting the GeoDR process will take some time, you probably need to setup 4 GeoDR copies to achieve the performance you want, 4 times per day